# When is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$ a Euclidean or principal ideal domain?

Tags: number-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

Let $d$ be an integer $\neq 1$ such that $d$ is not divisible by the power of any prime.Consider the ring $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$.My question is when is this ring a Euclidean domain,and when it is not an ED,when is this ring a PID?Is there any criterion to ensure this?How to understand by observation?

Note that $d$ may be negative also.

Comment: There's a lot of information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer#Principal_rings_of_quadratic_integers and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer#Euclidean_rings_of_quadratic_integers

Comment: A quick summary: The list of negative integers $d$ such that you get a PID is known. When $d$ is positive, the question is open. There is no easy to describe criterion.

Comment: Also note that ${\bf Z}[\sqrt d]$ is not always the same thing as the ring of integers of ${\bf Q}[\sqrt d]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no simple rule that classifies when $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is a PID or Euclidean when $d$ is squarefree and positive, and there is no reason to expect a simple rule. (But note, as Gerry Myerson points out, that $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is the "wrong ring" to be thinking about when $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ since the full ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d})$ in that case is the bigger ring $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{d})/2]$. The ring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is never a UFD for $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ for structural reasons.)
2. The list of *norm*-Euclidean real quadratic rings is known. See the Wikipedia page for quadratic integers, but note that it is about when the full ring of integers is *norm*-Euclidean. That is never $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ when $d \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, so if you discard such $d$ then you are left with $d = 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 19$. Note that being a Euclidean domain is a weaker property than being norm-Euclidean: maybe the ring is Euclidean with respect to some bizarre function, not its (absolute) norm function.  An example of that is $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{14}]$, which is not norm-Euclidean but was proved to be Euclidean by Malcolm Harper.
3. If you want to accept the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis for zeta-functions of number fields, then PID = Euclidean for real quadratic rings of algebraic integers. For example, if $d$ is positive, squarefree, and not $1 \bmod 4$ then $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{d}]$ is Euclidean (not necessarily norm-Euclidean!) if and only if it is a PID. Neither of these properties is easy to characterize, but the properties are equivalent to each other if you accept GRH.  This is a special case of a theorem of Weinberger in 1973: GRH for zeta-functions of all number fields implies the ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ of a number field $K$ is Euclidean if it is a PID (has class number $1$) and the unit group $\mathcal O_K^\times$ is infinite. Weinberger's paper is
   *On Euclidean rings of algebraic integers*, pp. 321-332 in
   "Analytic number theory'' (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XXIV).
   Amer. Math. Soc., Providence (1973).

Comment: The third point looks very interesting, where can I find these results? Can you please provide some references to it?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter I added a reference to the original paper.  If you google "Riemann hypothesis Weinberger" or "Riemann hypothesis Euclidean ring of integers" then you'll find information about this paper and related work.  See also Lenstra's paper *On Artin's conjecture and Euclid's algorithm in global fields*, 
Invent. Math. 42 (1977), 201-224.